# ERROR AL CAMBIAR EL NOMBRE EN HTML Y PHP

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola, descargue esta pag que se llama MIKHMON que en la barra tiene el nombre MIKHMON cada que se lo quiero cambiar me tira error, no intento venderlo solo le quisiera poner mi nombre en ves de MIKHMON[image: AQUI YA ME TIRO EL ERROR LUEGO DE QUE CAMBIE LA PALABRA MIKHMON Y LA REMPLAZO POR LA PALABRA TEMA]

[image: AQUI YA EDITO LA PALABRA MIKHMON Y LA REMPLAZO POR TEMA LUEGO QUE LA REMPLAZO YA ME SALE EL ERROR]

Comment: Busca todos lo llamados a `brand` a ver si hay un script que impide cambiarlo.

Comment: Como hago eso disculpa, se poco de esto